# Importing Excel or csv in mongodb with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, php-mongodb

I need to know which would be faster way(Excel or csv) to insert large set of data in mongodb with cakephp2.x and why?

Comment: which? both pretty much the same. But I would still use csv as a non-proprietary format. But your question is still too broad for this site.

Comment: I've done this for csv files, using the Datasources.CsvSource downloaded from here: https://github.com/cakephp/datasources.  Let me know if you want code, I can post it.  I found that importing 16,000 records from a csv took around a minute on my dev machine, if this helps.